# How to calculate the percentage between 3 numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, calculator, percentage

How to calculate the percentage between 3 numbers in javascript?

valueStart: 120
valueEnd: 970

valueCenter:360 | need to redeem this value where it remains within the standard of 0 to 100%

The value of 120 equals 0%.
The value of 970 equals 100¨%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const start_value = 120;
const end_value = 970;

const calculate_percentage = (input_number) => {
  if(input_number < start_value) return 0;
  if(input_number > end_value) return 100;
  return (input_number-start_value)/(end_value-start_value)*100;
}


console.log(calculate_percentage(120))
console.log(calculate_percentage(500))
console.log(calculate_percentage(970))
```

Answer (score -3):

Somebody good at math would be able to turn three numbers into three percentages out of 100.

```
var ywidth = (+100-xwidth); //var zwidth = (+100-ywidth);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).